# gSOAP wrong proxy C++ class generated for multiple operations

Tags: web-services, wsdl, gsoap

I have the following part of `wsdl` file:

```
<wsdl:binding name="Binding" type="intf:PortType">
    <wsdlsoap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="rpc"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="Op1">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="Op1" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="services:ca" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Op2">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="Op2" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="services:ca" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Op3">
        <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="Op3" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <wsdlsoap:body use="encoded" namespace="services:ca" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

The problem is that `soapcpp2` generates `soapBidingProxy.h` files iteratively, effectively overwriting old file (for `Op1` and `Op2`), and leaving me with proxy class for `Op3` only. Is this `soapcpp2` bug, or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information, you don't run soapcpp2 on .wsdl files so what does your build script look like, can you post a simple sequence of commands that replicates the problem?  What version of gsoap are you running and on what OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that in the `input body namespace`. If the `namespace` is the same for all operations, the generated file is only one, and includes all the methods. Thanks All.